# Change datamember name based on method

Tags: wcf, datacontract, datamember

```
 [DataContract()]
 public class Contract
 {
    .........
Some Properties with DataMembers Attribute.
    ............
    ..............

  [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
  public string Name  {   get;   set;  }
 }
```

I have above class and I have two web methods (operations)

In 1st web method I want to expose Name as FirstName and in 2nd web method expose Name as LastName.

I don't want to create separate data contracts.

Please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection and change the value of the attribute at runtime depending on which method you in currently. Check out these links on StackOverflow:

[How to set attributes values using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160476/how-to-set-attributes-values-using-reflection)
[Change Attribute's parameter at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269/change-attributes-parameter-at-runtime)

But I think the best way would be to either have 2 separate contracts or create a contract with both properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement a surrogate to special-case this type during serialization. As an example, see the [Data Contract Surrogate sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751540.aspx).