# How can I set the value of C# Custom Attibutes?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set attributes values using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160476/how-to-set-attributes-values-using-reflection)

How can I set the value of custom attribute, this custom attribute is used in the member of class object. Consider below member with its attribute.

```
[DataMember]
    [Decorater(false, false)]
    [DecroraterUpdt(false, false)]
    [PricingSchema(false, false)]
    public string UniqueID
    {
        get { return uniqueId; }
        set { uniqueId = value; }
    }
```

I want to set Pricing schema attribute's value.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its not possible please check answer on this
[How to set attributes values using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160476/how-to-set-attributes-values-using-reflection)

Comment: Do ***not*** post links to duplicate questions. These questions need to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

What is the property name?

The syntax is [AttributeName(constructorValues, propertyValues)]

i.e.

```
[PricingSchema(false, false, Property1="My Property", Property2="Prop 2")]
```