# How to Get WebGetAttribute from MethodInfo Using Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, reflection

When I run this Code attrs values is empty

```
IEnumerable<object> attrs = ((typeof(Data).GetMethods().Select
(a => a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebGetAttribute),true))));  
WebGetAttribute wg= attrs.First() as WebGetAttribute;    // wg is null
```

**this is my class to reflect:**

```
public class Data
    {
       [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetData")]
       string GetData(int value)
       {
           return "";
       }
    }
```

Please I need Help to Know this information (Method Type/ResponseFormat/UriTemplate) about each method in WCF service

Comment: perhap's I misunderstood the question (I seem to be in a bad day for understanding questions ;-), but shouldn't it be a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebInvokeAttribute)... ?

Comment: I try WebInvokeAttribute but not working

Comment: GetMethods without using BindingFlags parameters returns only the public methods. GetData seems to be private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to select NonPublic methods or the correct attribute type.

You may give a try to :

```
IEnumerable<object> attrs = 
     typeof(Data).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic)
      .SelectMany(a => a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebInvokeAttribute),true));  

WebInvokeAttribute wi = attrs.First() as WebInvokeAttribute ;
```

Comment: jbl this code work successful but when i put class Data to WCF Service     that contains interface (IData) and class (Data) this code not working

Comment: @user2678754 isn't the attribute on IData ? If so, it is on this interface that you should call your code, not Data. Or you can inspect all typeof(Data).GetInterfaces() in search for a WebInvoke attribute

Comment: i do that but still not working:                                            `MyService.Service1Client obj = new MyService.Service1Client();
  Type[]ins= obj.GetType().GetInterfaces();
  MethodInfo t=  ins[2].GetMethod("GetData");  // this my interface
  WebInvokeAttribute wii =     t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebInvokeAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as WebInvokeAttribute;`

Comment: Can i fill WebInvokeAttribute?

Comment: @user2678754 Difficult to tell here, but the number 2 in ins[2] seems like a magic number here. Are you sure it is IData ? I guess you should try to select the interface which has a ServiceContract attribute.

Comment: @user2678754 seems like you can http://stackoverflow.com/a/51282/1236044 but it is not recommended http://stackoverflow.com/a/2160498/1236044 One of the reason could be that you don't control the flow and don't know if third party code has read the value once and for all before you change it.

Answer (score 0):

jbl is correct. Without the BindingFlags parameter, GetMethods will not return non-public methods. Also, as WebInvokeAttribute doesn't inherit WebGetAttribute it will not be returned by GetCustomAttributes.

The following code will select the WebInvokeAttributes for all public and non-public methods:

```
IEnumerable<object> attrs = typeof(Data)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebInvokeAttribute), true));
```