# .NET Reflection to set attributes on my runtime objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, reflection, attributes

I am having a ASP.NET MVC project where I need to read a dynamic table and display it in a Grid.

My framework supports binding static types to Grids, simply by adding attributes to the static type properties e.g. [Grid], [Key], [GridColumn(Name="Id", Order=1, IsHidden=true)]

I am therefore building a dynamic object with reflection and I am assigning all the required metadata to allow the framework read my dynamic object Grid.

Although I have managed to assign with reflection all the required attributes that have no properties and I think I know how to do it for attributes that take constructor parameters, I am struggling to set the properties of Name, Order, IsHidden of the GridColumnAttribute (which does not accept parameters in the framework)

Do you know any way of doing it?

I found that Jon in [How to set attributes values using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160476/how-to-set-attributes-values-using-reflection) mentioned it is not possible but then why is it possible to do it with constructor parameters and not public properties of the attribute?

If you think it is possible, I would appreciate code example.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to prove this is not possible... but that would somehow frighten me if reflection could change, for example, passive security checks.

```
[PrincipalPermission(Security.Demand, Role="BUILTIN\\Administrators"]
void SomeVerySecuredStuff()
{
   //...
}
```

I'm probably not the most trusted source for reflection, but **I really hope** that it cannot be achieved.