# set a value to the attribute at run time

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, attributes

I have a namespace that contains some classes, one of the classes I'm working on contains properties, where each proprty has an attribute associated with it, as the follwing

```
namespace Local.Business
{
    [DynamoDBTable("myTableName")]     
    public class Business
    {
        [DynamoDBHashKey("PK")] 
        public string MunId {get; set;}

        [DynamoDBRangeKey("SK")]
        public string Id {get; set;}

        [DynamoDBProperty("Dba")] 
        public string Dba {get; set;} 
    }
}
```

the string "myTableName" need to be determined at runtime(by calling a function or reading it from other class's property)
How can I achieve that, please?

Comment: It's a bad idea to try and edit the data stored in attributes, but if you really need to then you'll need to use reflection.

Comment: have a look on this so question [C# How to set attributes values using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160476/how-to-set-attributes-values-using-reflection)

Comment: how can change it using reflection? thanks @sean

Comment: @Sean that just doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/08b20ed8fd7c4da714028a15eb1893d0

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is inherently flawed. You *kinda can ish* change attributes *sort of, sometimes*, but there's a good chance that whatever is consuming the attributes **won't see the change**, which makes it entirely pointless.

Basically: you need to find another way of reconfiguring `DynamoDB` at runtime. This isn't it.

---

For the "kinda can ish":

- you can *materialize* attributes, and if they're mutable, change the copies you have; but when *other* code materializes the attributes, they'll get *different unrelated versions*, which will not have any changes you have made
- there *is* an API that supports this concept (`System.ComponentModel`), but: most attribute consumers *do not use that API* - it is mostly just UI binding tools (think `PropertyGrid`, `DataGridView`, etc) that would take any notice of it - because they are expecting to work with things like `DataTable` that require a different approach to metadata and reflection

Answer (score 0):

Set the table name value to empty string in the class file:

`[DynamoDBTable("")]`

During runtime, use the overloaded functions on `DynamoDBMapper` to pass `DynamoDBMapperConfig` configured with `TableNameOverride`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I deleted the table property and I gave the table name in the query

```
 dynamoDBOperationConfig = new DynamoDBOperationConfig();
 dynamoDBOperationConfig.OverrideTableName = "tableName";
 string munId = "1";
 var search = dynamoDBcontext.QueryAsync<Business>(munId, dynamoDBOperationConfig);
```

and It works fine, thank you all guys for helping